# How to change font size of body not affecting child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new here and trying to found a solution for a small part of my exercise with JS/jQuery. I'm trying to change the font size of the whole page and could implement that with the following code. What I'd like to do is not to change the font size of the clicked elements itself, in my case these are: #size1, #size2, #size3 and actually the text in span "Text size" also. I've seen some answers in another topics on how to change parent elements without affecting children, but it was about altering text and I could not apply it for my needs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//HTML
 <span>Text size :</span> 
            <a id="small" href="#" style="font-size: 0.8em" onclick="textgr(0.8)">A</a>
            <a id="middle" href="#" style="font-size: 1em" onclick="textgr(1)">A</a>
            <a id="large" href="#" style="font-size: 1.2em" onclick="textgr(1.2)">A</a>


//This works fine to change the font size on the whole page

function textgr(gr){
                    document.body.style.fontSize = gr + "em";
}    

//I've tried to pack this piece of code in the function above, but it would not do anything at all

function textgr2(){
        document.getElementById(small).style.fontSize = 0.8 + "em";
        document.getElementById(middle).style.fontSize = 1 + "em";
        document.getElementById(large).style.fontSize = 1.2 + "em";
}
```

Comment: Have you investigated the use of "REM" which allows you to set the document font size and then all future use allows a variation of that - rather than "em" which is the relative size of teh font to the elements parent.

Comment: Do not change the element styles, but change the body class. Next, using that, you can define whatever font sizes you need for any element on page.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I've checked the docu page on 'rem' and tried to use it, but it does not seem to do what I expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("text-size-controls").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var sz;
  var target = evt.target;
  if (evt.target.hasAttribute('data-size')) {
    sz = evt.target.getAttribute('data-size');
    document.getElementById("text-area").setAttribute("class",sz);
  }
});
```

```css
#text-size-controls {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#text-size-controls li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.small {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.medium {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.large {
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.0em;
}

.text {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="text-size-controls">
  <li data-size="small">Small</li>
  <li data-size="medium">Medium</li>
  <li data-size="large">Large</li>
</ul>
<div id="text-area">
<h1>
Header
</h1>
<p class="text">
  This is some text
</p>
</div>
```

Notice that **small**, **medium** and **large** set the font size in *pixels*, but that the **h1** and **.text** class adjust the size in *ems*.  This ensure the base size of the text is set and then proportionately adjusted.

This solution does not require jQuery.  I omitted it because the code in your question is JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. I guess, I could not explain that in a right way. With your code I get the same result, whenever I click on small, medium or large, they are changing their own size also and that is what I want to prevent. All three of them should keep the same size at all times.

Comment: @Timur - Sorry about that, I split the content so the controls are not in the div with the text.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That did the job, exactly what I wanted :) You are brilliant!